# Raspberry Pi: No module named nmap

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, nmap

I'm trying to install nmap for my pi, and I did this:

```
sudo apt-get install nmap
```

Which seemed to work just fine. But when I open a session of python and try to import nmap:

```
>>> import nmap
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named nmap
```

Which is super weird, because I installed it fine, or at least I thought. Any ideas why this might be happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you run

```
apt-cache show nmap
```

you'll see in the information about it that it's not a Python package. If you want, you can run `man nmap` to learn more about what you've installed, so far.

The Python package you want to install is probably named something like `python-nmap` or `python3-nmap`. You can run

```
apt-cache search nmap
```

to list all packages with "nmap" in the name, and see what its name really is, and then something like

```
sudo apt-get install python-nmap
```

to install.

Answer (score 2):

You can `sudo apt-get install python-nmap` for the same thing

Or you need to get the Python [NMap bindings from here](http://xael.org/norman/python/python-nmap/)

Answer (score 0):

if you run python2 its will work 
import nmap 
form nmap import*
but if u running python3 it's not gonna work

Answer (score 0):

for using nmap with python3 u have to download it from [here](https://xael.org/norman/python/python-nmap/). Then extract it and from the terminal run the following commands:

```
python setup.py install 
open python3 
import nmap 
from nmap import*
```